# How to create java client for elasticsearch

Tags: java, elasticsearch

Hey guys I'm new to ElasticSearch. What I want is how to store output of query in any format so that I can manipulate it later. Please help me.. !!

What I want is to set up java client and do all queries. Problem was I didn't know how to do it. and java api was not helpful. Thanks for helping me..

Comment: please provide details like what lang you are using, how you wanna change..

Comment: I'm just using command line with curl. and I want to store that response to any file format like txt or json

Comment: You gotta use any programming or even a bash script to do those... Can you use java program???

Comment: Yes. I can use java. but I didn't get how to use java - api. Its very confusing.

Comment: Your title is a bit misleading. It sounds like you want to write your own Java client, and what I'm getting here is you want to know "how to use it". Can you also define the context of your implementation. Are you doing this in an application or just command line? `curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/myindex/mytype' > output.txt` can help too, but not in an application. Please provide details

Comment: @Sthe yes I am using it for an application. but now I got it , I have to do it by setting up java client.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a java client for elastcsearch. its available in [gitbub repository](https://github.com/sidharthancr/elasticsearch-java-client).
It helps to understand better way to use java client for elasticsearch.

Comment: thanks..It worked for me. but I have some doubts on this can you help? Do Elastic search have any plugins or curl command for saving output json?If yes then please give me link of it.

Comment: sorry..i dont know any plugin like that..!